# How Can I Reduice The Size Of lib Folder in Apk for my Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, lib

Nearly 18 MB occuied by lib, how can I reduce it ?

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:18.2.0'


implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'`
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL1Y2.png]

Answer (score 0):

Your zie of apk have become bigger because of the third party library you have used in it , to overcome this simply you have to split your apk for different android ABi's

Then each ABI apk will have its separate Lib folder with small size ..

Or try create app bundels apk and publish on PlayStore play store will take care of it ☺️